# how to run a bash script from php?

Tags: php, bash, zend-framework, exec, sh

i am trying to sun a bash script when i update something:

```
public function reloadServer()
{
    exec ('/var/www/html/script', $y);
    Zend_Debug::dump($y);
}
```

this is the `script` file

```
#!/bin/bash
# test
ssh root@192.168.526.33 "server -rx reload"
echo "success"
```

what happens is that get the `success` message, but the command doesn't get run.
if i run the command manually it works just fine

note: i can't use `ssh2_exec` because of some problems on my server

any ideas on what is happening or how can i debug that bash script ?

Comment: Try to increase the verbosity of the ssh to maximum and show us what you get in $y. Optionally check if the return_var of the exec() is indeed 0. You can force ssh to go verbose by adding -vvv as its argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your command inside a subshell and tee its output:

```
#!/bin/bash
# test
( ssh root@192.168.526.33 "server -rx reload" ) 2>&1 | tee -a /some/where.log
echo "success"
```

Through that you'll see all the messages including possible messages from bash.

Comment: thanks, now i see a lot more info. I added `-vvv` as @Shadow Walker suggested and that showed me a lot more info.